# How to create a directive to show a tooltip on form field error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is my HTML:

```
<input id="email" type="text" name="email" class="form-control" ng-
model="user.email" required ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\[A-
Za-z]{2,4}$/" input-tooltip>
```

And my directive:

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('inputTooltip', function($timeout, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: ['^form', 'ngModel'],
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {

            var formCtrl = controllers[0],
                ngModelCtrl = controllers[1];

            function trigger() {
                $timeout(function() {
                    element.trigger('manual');
                }, 0);
            };

            var name = element[0].name;

            attrs.$set('tooltipTrigger', 'manual');
            attrs.$set('tooltipPlacement', 'top');
            attrs.$set('tooltipEnable', formCtrl.$name + '.' + name + '.$invalid');
            attrs.$set('tooltip', 'Invalid Email');

            ngModelCtrl.$viewChangeListeners.push(trigger);

            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    };
});
```

It seems to create the right HTML:

```
<input id="email" type="text" name="email" class="form-control ng-valid-
required ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-invalid ng-invalid-pattern ng-touched" ng-
model="user.email" required="" ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-
]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/" input-tooltip="" tooltip-trigger="manual" tooltip-
placement="top" tooltip-enable="form.email.$invalid" tooltip="Invalid Email">
```

The attributes are there and the trigger() function runs on input change, but no tooltip is shown.

Anything you find I'm doing wrong or could be doing better — I'm feeling there are some noob things in there — please let me know!

Thanks.

Comment: Is there another library you are referencing for the tooltip functionality?

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that, yes it's UI Bootstrap's tooltip

Comment: can you post a demo of this, on plunker for example?

Comment: If you want to show the tooltip immediately you're missing `$(element).tooltip('show');`

Comment: sorry for the delay, here's the plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/3diCxUBX4Nbefw6G8y35